# Python throwing ValueError: is not in list although it's there in list

Tags: python

I am populating a tuple by importing a CSV file in Python. Now when I try to get index of a value in that tuple, it gives `Value error: is not in list` although the value is present. Below is the code I am using along with the sample data.
Following is the content of csv

`IsNonPO,ApprovedState,ApprovalRecords/0/Comment,ApprovalRecords/0/Comment.Date`

I am using the following code

```
import csv
flist = [tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(open('D:\\result_IV.csv', 'rU'))]
print (flist)
x = flist.index('IsNonPO')
print(x)
```

Below is the output I get

```
 [('IsNonPO', 'ApprovedState', 'ApprovalRecords/0/Comment','ApprovalRecords/0/Comment.Date']
File "C:/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/Default/first.py", line 10, in <module>
 x = flist.index('IsNonPO')
ValueError: 'IsNonPO' is not in list
```

Comment: maybe not directly related but maybe you should consider loading and processing your file as follow: `with open('your_file.csv') as file: lines=tuple([f.strip().split(",") for f in file])` . Then to get the index of a value you can do something like `lines[0].index('IsNonPO')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is, You are parsing CSV content in tuple and then storing that tuple in a list.

```
    flist = [('IsNonPO', 'ApprovedState', 'ApprovalRecords/0/Comment','ApprovalRecords/0/Comment.Date')]
```

So to access the first row, use flist[0]

then to get the index of a value in tuple use:

```
    flist[0].index('IsNonPO')
```

Just change line 10 to:

```
    x = flist[0].index('IsNonPO')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't follow your data structure.

According to your code, what you get is a list of tuples. Each tuple represents one line, and each tuple item represents a value in the csv.

So for

```
IsNonPO,ApprovedState,ApprovalRecords/0/Comment,ApprovalRecords/0/Comment.Date
```

you should get

```
[('IsNonPO', 'ApprovedState', 'ApprovalRecords/0/Comment','ApprovalRecords/0/Comment.Date')]
```

(note the missing `)`after the closing `]`.

So indeed, the list doesn't contain the given string, but a tuple with the given string.

One approach could be

```
n, val = next((n, i) for n, i in enumerate(flist) if 'IsNonPO' in i)
```

which gives you the first item (and the tuple) which contains `'IsNonPO'`.

Then you can proceed with getting the index of `'IsNonPO'` in that tuple.

Of course, it depends on what you really want to achieve. If you always have only one row, [yashjain12yj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324243/296974) would work as well.